# c++: overloading + operator for a sparse matrix

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

```
void add(sparseMatrix<T> &b, sparseMatrix<T> &c); // c is output

sparseMatrix<T> operator+(sparseMatrix<T> &b);
```

I'm creating a sparse matrix which is made up of an arrayList of singly linked lists of matrix terms (matrix terms contain the row, column, and value). I'm having trouble overloading the + operator. I have an add method which works fine, but when I try to use it to overload the + operator I get the following errors:

```
sparseMatrix.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
sparseMatrix.cpp:268: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘c = sparseMatrix<T>::operator+(sparseMatrix<T>&) [with T = int](((sparseMatrix<int>&)(& b)))’
sparseMatrix.cpp:174: note: candidates are: sparseMatrix<T>& sparseMatrix<T>::operator=(sparseMatrix<T>&) [with T = int]
make: *** [sparseMatrix] Error 1
```

Here is my implementation for the overloaded + operator:

```
sparseMatrix<T> sparseMatrix<T>::operator+(sparseMatrix<T> &b) 
{
        sparseMatrix<T> c;

 add(b, c);
 return c;

}
```

The line in main that gives the error is c = a + b (a, b, c are all sparse matrices). Note that if I do a.add(b,c) everything works fine. I have also overloaded the = operator which works when I do a = b etc. but it seems to be complaining about it in the error message I posted. I'm really not sure what the problem is. Any ideas?

Comment: hmm, from QUICKLY scanning your question, confirm the output of the + operator. Does it return what it should?

Comment: I can't even get it to compile when I try to use the + operator so I can't check the output

Comment: You might be interested in `boost::ublas::sparse_matrix`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix_sparse.htm

Answer (score 7):

> note: candidates are: sparseMatrix& sparseMatrix::operator=(sparseMatrix&)

Your `operator=` should take a **const** reference.

If the reference isn't const, it can't be bound to a temporary, so the assignment operator can't be used for the temporary created by `a + b`.

(The same is true for `operator+`, here also the argument should be `const sparseMatrix<T> &`. Additionally this method should be declared as const, since it doesn't modify the object it is called on.)

Comment: I'm still learning c++ and const always gives me problems. When I try to add const to the operator= method like you said I get the following error: sparseMatrix.cpp:183: error: passing ‘const arrayList<chain<matrixTerm<int> > >’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘T& arrayList<T>::get(int) [with T = chain<matrixTerm<int> >]’ discards qualifiers: line 183 is: for (int j = 0; j < b.termsList.get(i).size(); j++)

Comment: @murkilator: Looks like your `get()` method also should be const, like `int get(int i) const {...}`. Methods that don't change the object they are called on should be declared as const, so that the compiler knows it is ok to use them on constant objects.

Answer (score 0):

sth: has correctly diagnosed the problem:

But I would make your operators more standard.

```
class sparseMatrix
{
   sparseMatrix(sparseMatrix const& copy);
   sparseMatrix& operator=(sparseMatrix const& copy);

   sparseMatrix& add(sparseMatrix const& value) // Add value to the current matrix
   {
       // Do Work.
       return *this;
   }

   // Re-use add to implement the += operator.
   sparseMatrix& operator+=(sparseMatrix const& rhs)
   {
       return add(rhs);
   }

   // Two things here:
   //
   // Implement the operator + in terms of the operator +=
   //
   // This basically means that you make a copy of one parameter then add the other
   // value two it. Because + is symmetric it does not matter which you copy and which
   // you add to the copy.
   //
   // So we pass the parameter by value this will provide an implicit copy
   // generated by the compiler. This will also help the compiler with NRVO
   // Then we just add (*this) to the copy of the rhs.
   sparseMatrix operator+(sparseMatrix rhs)
   {
       return rhs += *this; 
   }
}
```